# Bad Jasper Studio chart size in Excel ("fit to cell size" and not in "original size")

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I use `Jaspersoft Studio 6.11.0` and when I export my report in excel (.xlsx) the charts size appear to be in **"fit to cell size"** and not **"in original size"**.

I spend a lot of time to find hacks and parameters but I can't find a solution. I want to ensure that chart appear in it's original size in excel. The original size of the chart is `640x480`.

I put a screen capture as you can easily see the problem

Thanks in advance.

[image: screen capture of the problem]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't really a code question, which is our specialty. You might try https://superuser.com or a product support forum.

Comment: I just post the question on superuser.com thanks for the tip dude.